# Combining three RGB images into a single RGB image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I have three RGB images, but each one has only 1 non-zero channel (ie. one has a red channel with 0's in the blue and green channels) and I want to combine them into a single RGB image with the correct channel from each.

I apologise for my phrasing, I don't know much of the terminology (which really isn't helping my search queries)

Here are my images: [Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyrqR.jpg) [Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xel7l.jpg) [Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKQW4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `Image.merge` here and take the appropriate channels from each image. Note that I'm using `requests.get(...)` and `BytesIO` here to pull down from the linked images but you can just use `Image.open(...)` directly on the filename instead if you have them locally.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests

red = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKQW4.jpg').content)) 
green = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xel7l.jpg').content))
blue = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyrqR.jpg').content))
combined = Image.merge('RGB', (red.getchannel('R'), green.getchannel('G'), blue.getchannel('B'))
combined.save('output_image_name.jpg')
```

And that'll give you something like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use OpenCV:

```
blue = cv2.imread("blue.jpg")
red = cv2.imread("red.jpg")
green = cv2.imread("green.jpg")

merge = blue + red + green
cv2.imwrite('merge.jpg', merge)
```

[image]