# Merged Image is All Black

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I run this function it splits the image into three files of red/green/blue. Those images look OK. However, the merge logic creates a completely black result.

```
def split_image_into_bands(filename):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    data = img.getdata()

    red = [(d[0], 0, 0) for d in data]
    green = [(0, d[1], 0) for d in data]
    blue = [(0, 0, d[2]) for d in data]


    img.putdata(red)    # This overwrites whatever was in the image
    img.save(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_red.jpg")
    img.putdata(green)
    img.save(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_green.jpg")
    img.putdata(blue)
    img.save(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_blue.jpg")

    # Put the 3 images back together to show that it works
    rimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    rimage.putdata(red)
    gimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    gimage.putdata(green)
    bimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    bimage.putdata(blue)
    img = Image.merge(img.mode, (rimage, gimage, bimage))
    img.save(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_merged.jpg")
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/q/60352546/2836621

Comment: I didn't. Please read both questions.

Answer (score 0):

PIL is probably being confused about your arrays being RGB arrays where it expects single-channel (grayscale) arrays.

This works fine (and is faster due to the use of `zip` to transpose the data array).

```py
def split_image_into_bands(filename):
    basename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    img = Image.open(filename)
    red, green, blue = zip(*img.getdata())  # each channel as a single-channel array
    rimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    rimage.putdata(red)
    gimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    gimage.putdata(green)
    bimage = Image.new("L", img.size)
    bimage.putdata(blue)
    img = Image.merge(img.mode, (rimage, gimage, bimage))
    img.save(basename + "_merged.jpg")
```

Comment: You can use use `red = img.getchannel('R')` etc... which should be fairly swift then put 'em back together directly from the channels eg: `Image.merge('RGB', (red, green, blue))` (kind of like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58722340/combining-three-rgb-images-into-a-single-rgb-image)

Answer (score 0):

How about you use **`opencv`** to process the image, its quite fast as compared to `PIL`,
You may want to try the following code,

```
import os
import cv2

def split_image_into_bands(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    b, g, r = cv2.split(img)  # For BGR image

    # save the channels RGB
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_red.jpg", r)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_green.jpg", g)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_blue.jpg", b)

    # merge the channels
    img_merged = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + "_merged.jpg", img_merged)
```